# What is the location of all the solr dependencies source after building solr 9.3 source?

Tags: windows, gradle, solr

In my organization we are upgrading from **Solr 8** to **Solr 9.3**.
In our upgrade process for third party open source application we usually download the source code, build it and then use the compiled application. We also build all the dependencies source.
Now solr uses **gradle** from **Solr 9** onwards.
When I had build **Solr 9.2.1**, all the dependencies source were copied in **C:\Users<user_name>.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1** in windows with *source.jar name along with the compiled jar file.
But when I tried again with **Solr 9.3** and also again with **Solr 9.2**, it is not working.
I also don't remember if I did anything different at the first time when it worked.

Please can someone help me with this.